# (Fluent) NHibernate: HasMany/References (bidirectional) + Cascade Save

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

How do I configure mappings for bidirectional mapping in the scenario of *X references Y, Y has many Xs*, so that when I add many Xs to the Y instance and save Y instance, it'll work properly?

to make the problem clear, here's the code:

**ClientCompany** model has `HasMany` **ContactPerson** related models:

```
public class ClientCompany
{
    // .... 
    public virtual ISet<ContactPerson> ContactPeople { get; set; }
}

// mapping:
HasMany(x => x.ContactPeople)
            .AsSet()
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.All();
```

the **ContactPerson** has not-nullable "ClientCompany" field referencing the parent company:

```
public class ContactPerson
{
    // ....
    public virtual ClientCompany ClientCompany { get; set; }
}

References(x => x.ClientCompany).Not.Nullable();
```

calling this code:

```
sess.Save(new ClientCompany()
            {                    
                ContactPeople = new HashSet<ContactPerson>()
                {
                    new ContactPerson()
                }
            });
```

causes this exception:

> not-null property references a null or transient value
>   xxxx.ContactPerson.ClientCompany

this is just simplified case, I'm using AutoMapper in my real-world project so **setting the reference manually** is **not the solution**

Answer (score 3):

The most important thinkg in ORM world, namely when using NHibernate, is:

> ALWAYS set **both** sides of relation.

This is valid way, how to set both sides:

```
var person = new ContactPerson();
var company = new ClientCompany
{                    
    ContactPeople = new HashSet<ContactPerson>()
    {
        person,
    },
};
person.ClientCompany = company

sess.Save(company);
```

By mapping is the `Person` declared as responsible for its relation (the inverse mapping **`.Inverse()`**).

And that means, that it must have set the relation to its parent. This relation is used later for INSERT statement... and it cannot be null.

There is no need to save company and person separatelly. The **only essential** and **absolutely important** thing is to set both reference sides. That is a MUST.

Not sure what you can do with auto mapper... but some kind of wrapping/shielding of the bi-directional setting could be some special method on the POCO object:

```
public class ClientCompany
{
    // .... 
    public virtual ISet<ContactPerson> ContactPeople { get; set; }
    public virtual AddPerson(ContactPerson person)
    {
        ContactPeople = ContactPeople ?? new HashSet<ContactPerson>();
        ContactPeople.Add(person);
        person.ClientCompany = this;
    }
}
```

Now we just have to call `AddPerson()` at the right time...

Comment: Thank you! I thought I can somehow let it "auto" set reference when the "Save" is called on the "company" object. This way it'd be possible to let the AutoMapper do the magic.

Comment: The reference must be set explicitly. It is really crucial. If you make this, the rest will be handled by NHibernate ... Another way to go *(but I am not sure what your auto mapper is capable of)* is to create special method **`AddPerson()`** and implement there the bi-directional setting *(parent-to-child, child-to-parent)* ... But then AutoMapper must be able to call such a method `AddPerson()`